# How to change malayalam unicode fonts style

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

i  was tying to add a new malayalam unicode font to web page.

```css
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "Meera";
    src: url(Meera.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p{ 
    font-family: "Meera";
}
</style>
```

```html
<p>മലയാളം</p>
```

have Meera.ttf and this is my CSS code

but font doest changed it still displays the text in default font of the browser (Nirmala UI)

Is there any error in my code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see a successful request in network/fonts in console? (that' s chrome)

Comment: Is the ttf file in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: Please edit your question, because the snippet that is supposed to be CSS code is a single word, and not CSS code at all.

Comment: Am getting 304 error in console @Olena Horal

Comment: Am getting two warning message's

* failed to decode downloaded font http://localhost/font/meera.ttf

*otf parsing error :FFTM:invalid table ofset

Comment: @MrLister yeah its in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "Meera";
    src: url(Meera.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p{ 
    font-family: "Meera";
}
</style>
```

```html
<p>മലയാളം</p>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.